# ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT on Electron App but redirect works properly on browser app

Tags: oauth, electron, fastapi

I have an Electron app and an Angular app in the same codebase, on login it calls a function in FastAPI that redirects to the dashboard page ("/" route) when the user is authenticated. This redirection works perfectly on browser when I redirect to localhost:4200 and putting "rtrader://" in my browser's URL opens the electron app so I think the custom protocol is set correctly but for some reason the redirect isn't working when I use the electron app and it's giving me the `ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT` error. I don't understand why this is happening and I would like some help.

This is my FastAPI endpoint:

```py
@router.get("/login/callback")
async def login_callback(code: str, session: dict = Depends(get_session), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    """
    Handles the OAuth2 callback from Discord, authenticates the user, and associates the obtained token
    with the user in the database.

    :param code: The authorization code provided by Discord as part of the OAuth2 flow.
    :type code: str
    :param session: The session dictionary associated with the request.
    :type session: dict
    :param db: The database session used to interact with the application's database.
    :type db: Session (from SQLAlchemy or your chosen ORM)

    :return: A JSON object containing the application token for the authenticated user.
    :rtype: dict

    :raises HTTPException: If the code is missing or if authentication with Discord fails.
    """
    if not code:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Code is required")

    data = {
        "client_id": os.getenv("CLIENT_ID"),
        "client_secret": os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET"),
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": code,
        "redirect_uri": os.getenv("API_URL") + "login/callback",
    }
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

    try:
        response = requests.post("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token", data=data, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raises an HTTPError if the HTTP request returned an unsuccessful status code
        token = response.json()

        # Check if token contains the required keys
        if 'access_token' not in token:
            raise ValueError("Access token missing in response")

        # Retrieve the user's information from Discord
        headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token['access_token']}"}
        user_response = requests.get(os.getenv("DISCORD_API_URL") + "users/@me", headers=headers)
        discord_user = user_response.json()

        # Check if the user exists in your database
        user_repository = UserRepository(db)
        user = user_repository.get_user_by_id(discord_user['id'])

        if not user:
            user = user_repository.add_user(discord_user['id'])

        # Save tokens in the session instead of the database
        session["access_token"] = token["access_token"]

        # Create an application token or session
        app_token = create_token(user.id)

        # Save the token in the user session
        session["app_token"] = app_token

        # Redirect to the Angular app
        redirect_url = os.getenv("APP_URL")
        return RedirectResponse(url=redirect_url)

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=503, detail="Service unavailable") from e
    except ValueError as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Unexpected response format") from e
```

APP_URL is `APP_URL=rtrader://`. As I said before if I put this URL as localhost:4200 the redirect works properly but it's currently giving me an error from electron.

This is my `main.js` script:

```js
const { app, protocol, net, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const { pathToFileURL } = require('url');
const path = require('path');

let win; // Global reference to the main window
const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();

protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  {
    scheme: 'rtrader',
    privileges: {
      standard: true,
      secure: true,
      supportFetchAPI: true
    }
  }
]);

// Handling default protocol client for development and production
if (process.defaultApp) {
  if (process.argv.length >= 2) {
    app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('rtrader', process.execPath, [path.resolve(process.argv[1])]);
  }
} else {
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('rtrader');
}

/**
 * Creates the main window of the application with specified properties.
 */
function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1366,
    height: 768,
    icon: 'dist/rtrader/assets/logo.ico',
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      nativeWindowOpen: true, // Enables native window opening
    }
  });

  // Load the main HTML file of the application
  win.loadFile('dist/rtrader/index.html').then(r => {});

  // Maximize the window to fullscreen
  win.maximize();

  // Open Developer Tools (Optional)
  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Hide the default menu
  win.setMenu(null);

  // Handle window closed event
  win.on('closed', function () {
    win = null;
  });
}

  // Create window when Electron is ready
  app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

  // Handle custom protocol (Note: This example code may require additional context)
  app.whenReady().then(() => {
    protocol.handle('rtrader', (req) => {
      const requestURL = new URL(req.url);
      // Extract the file path from the request URL, and adjust as needed
      const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist/rtrader', requestURL);

      console.log('Trying to load:', filePath); // Debugging line
      // Return the file using net.fetch
      return net.fetch(pathToFileURL(filePath).toString());
    });
  });

  // Quit application when all windows are closed (except on macOS)
  app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit();
    }
  });

  // macOS specific process to recreate window when activated
  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (win == null) {
      createWindow();
    }
});
```

What I expected to happen: Redirect working on both Electron app and Angular app
What actually resulted: Redirect working on Angular app when I set APP_URL to localhost:4200 but not working on Electron app when I set APP_URL to rtrader://